# Is there a minimum RU point-read cost in Azure CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

From the CosmosDB documentation on [Request Units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units):

> The cost to do a point read (fetching a single item by its ID and partition key value) for a 1-KB item is one Request Unit (or one RU).

Is 1 RU an absolute minimum? What would be the cost of e.g., a 0.5-KB document point-read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is 1 RU an absolute minimum? What would be the cost of e.g., a 0.5-KB
> document point-read?

Yes. I ran a very simple test with a document which is less than 1KB in size and noticed the RU charge for point read. The RU charge was 1 for that operation.